# Issue with updating model on AJAX "POST"

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to update my model without refreshing the page. I'm using a wysiwyg inline editor that I have on many places on my page. The editor can be placed anywhere on the page, it could look like this:

```
<div id="1" class="click2edit">@Model.Header</div>

<div id="2" class="click2edit">@Model.Content</div>
```

Each editors `div` have a SaveButton that goes to this jquery, ajax below.
What it does is: When I hit the save button for example the `<div id="1" class="click2edit">@Model.Header</div>`
It posts the that divs id and its content (in this case `@Model.Header`). And my whole `@model`

```
$('.click2edit').click(function () {
    var modelDataJson = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
    $(this).note({ focus: true });
    var activeId = (this.id);
    activeId = activeId.replace(/ /g, '');
    $(this).note({
        oninit: function () {
            $('#saveFileBtn').click(function (event) {
                $('#previewBtn').click(),
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/SaveContent',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        model: modelDataJson,
                        activeId: activeId,
                        contentToUpdate: $("div#" + activeId).html()
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("sucess");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
                $('.click2edit').destroy();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Then in my mvc-controller it puts the new content in right place and saves to my db.
That is done by replacing the whole old model, with the new one that is posted from the view:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void SaveContent(string model, string activeId, string contentToUpdate)
{
    //my logic to save to db is here...
}
```

The problem is:
My model in my razor-view don't get updated. Everything works fine if I'm just saving one of my editors  content. But when I'm trying to save another before I refresh my page, it is not getting updated. 
That is because my razor-views `@model` is still holding the old values.
So basiclly the only value that is updated is the last one I will save.
Can I in someway refresh my views @model without refreshing the whole page?

EDIT:
Iv'e now changed my success-function so it looks like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#1").text(data.Header);
},
```

But the models value of this does not gets updated. the data I'm sending back from the success-function is my Model as Json.

```
<div id="1" class="click2edit">@Model.Header</div>
```

Comment: The Ajax is two parts: 1) Updating the data behind the scenes without a postback (you have this part), 2) Updating the view to reflect these changes.  The only way really to have a new "Model" be rendered as your whole view would be to have the portion of the view that needs changed to be returned as complete markup by your action (usually you don't want void methods as actions in MVC).  You need to change the view in whatever way you want in your success function(where data is given by your action method).

Comment: @xDaevax Thanks for the answer. Do you mean that what I need to do is to have my void-method as an ActionResult instead. And with that, return my whole model to my sucess function. And when it is returned to the sucess I need to do something there to make my content updated? I don't really getting it.

Comment: @xDaevax I'm now changed my method to ActoinResult and return my Model as Json. And the json is getting back to the views success data. If that is a correct approch, what shold I do then to update my model with those values?

Comment: That depends on what you need.  If you are just updating the header and the content properties of the model (assuming these are returned in the data argument of `success`), then you just need to target these divs and replace their content inside of your success method: `$("#1").text(data.Header);` for example.

Comment: What is the JSON returned by the controller action?  You may want to have it be a `JsonResult` instead of an `ActionResult`.

Comment: this is the return content: `{"Header":"some header","Content":"some content"}` If I'm trying to alert data.Header in my success method I get "undefiend"

Comment: If I'm alerting just `data` I get the whole model.

Comment: Try using this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/.  For example: `var newModel = jQuery.parseJSON(data); alert(newModel.Header);`

Comment: I tried that, the alert shows the right value. But when I'm using this: `$("#1").text(data.Header);` The model not gets updated

Comment: @xDaevax I'm using the code you gave me. Right content on the page getting updated. But page model values is not!So if I try to save `<div id="2" class="click2edit">@Model.Content</div>` and then`<div id="1" class="click2edit">@Model.Header</div>` just the values of .Header is getting saved correct because Model.Content-values get overwritten by the models starting-values.It saves each correct, but my model still holding the start-values I sent to the view in first place. Only way to get it right, is to refresh the page between the savings.Must be another way instead of refreshing the page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60635/discussion-between-xdaevax-and-user3228992).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a summary of our chat:

An MVC model is an instance that contains data built by on the server that is used to control the rendering of, and provide data to, a view.  HTTP's stateless nature dictates that the only time you can access this server-side data is when the view is in the process of being rendered.  Once it's rendered, it is completely in the hands of the browser and whatever data that was present in the server-side object is released from memory.

After this point, you can no longer use the Razor server-side syntax of `@if` or `@model` to access the model data (the model as it existed when the page was being rendered no longer exists).  Instead, you should work with the DOM and JavaScript objects to update the look and contents of the page (while saving data using Ajax on the server side).  Without doing a full-page post your only option is to use client-side code (JavaScript) to manipulate what the user sees (hence the name: View) so that what they are seeing matches the changes that have occurred after the Ajax POST.

I have created a Gist here that demonstrates these concepts: https://gist.github.com/xDaevax/f5e192c03f6a2bfc2cdb

Essentially you would need code similar to the following for your controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AjaxMvcTest.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        //
        // GET: /Home/


        public ActionResult Index() {
            HomeModel model = new HomeModel();
            model.Header = "Default Header";
            model.Content = "People assume that time is a strict progression of cause to effect, but actually, from a non-linear, non-subjective viewpoint, it's more like a big ball of wibbly-wobbly... timey-wimey... stuff.";
            return View(model);
        }

        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public JsonResult SaveContent(UpdateDataModel updateRequest) {
            //Do some stuff
            HomeModel newModel = new HomeModel();
            newModel.Content = updateRequest.Content;
            newModel.Header = updateRequest.Header;

            return Json(newModel);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a view that would be used with the above controller:

```
@model HomeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="1" class="click2edit">@Model.Header</div>
<br />
<div id="2" class="click2edit">@Model.Content</div>
<br />
Header:&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="HeaderInput" id="HeaderInput" value="@Model.Header" />
<br />
Content: <textarea name="ContentInput" id="ContentInput">@Model.Content</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" id="saveFileBtn" value="Save" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#saveFileBtn").click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/SaveContent',
                type: 'POST',
                data: getFormData(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#1").text(data.Header);
                    $("#2").text(data.Content);
                    $("#HeaderInput").val(data.Header);
                    $("#ContentInput").val(data.Content);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function getFormData() {
    //Convert the form data to a javascript object
        var dataToSubmit = {
            Header: $("#HeaderInput").val(),
            Content: $("#ContentInput").val(),
            TimeStamp: new Date(),
            Id: 1
       };

       return dataToSubmit;
    }
</script>
```

In this way, you can see that the client-side (JavaScript) code is responsible for updating the view in the `success` callback of the `ajax` method after the controller has done the work and the `getFormData()` method is used to convert the form values into a JavaScript object that the MVC model binder can read and convert into a .NET server-side model.  If you didn't want to do this manually, you could use JQuery's `serialize` method to serialize the whole form, providing the form values match your server-side model.