# How can I avoid fetching model data again after a post method in an MVC architecture?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I'm using Asp.net and MVC pattern.

I have a huge collection of data (logs identified by an ID) and a user can request (some of) them. The request is handled by ElasticSearch. Therefore the elastic response is a subset of the huge collection and it is loaded into a viewmodel and I don't want to store it in a local DB because it may take up too much space quickly (and that I only need it for the user session). Such request can take a lot of time to return (several minutes).

Through a PostMethod using Ajax, the user can add "a category" to a log. These Categories are stored in a local database but are also displayed in the view.

My view model looks like this:

```cs
    //elastic data, not stored in database and comes from the elastic request
    public IEnumerable<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    
    //take the id of a Log and associate a category, comes from the local database
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

And my view (simplified, I have a lot of other fields to display):

```html
<table>
     <tbody>
           @{foreach (var l in Model.Logs)
              {
                 <tr>
                      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => l.Message)</td>
                      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Category.First(e => e.ID == l.Id).CategoryName)</td>
                 </tr>
              }
           }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the user add a "category" it is done through a post request. I would like to display the logs that were loaded in the view but with the updated categories. Unfortunately when I do the post request I get a new ViewModel and so loose all the logs data and I can't afford to request them again (because it takes so much time).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25848937) proposes to use JavaScript to update the view. But my logs data are *really* rich and parsing the dom would be extremely tedious and terrible performances wise.

I'm looking for a cleaner way to achieve my goal, even if it need a change in the current architecture.
I think I need to cache the elastic response but and I don't know how it should be done cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest optimizing your return data.  The fact that your call to get a subset of data takes several minutes is taking too long, which is causing you to avoid making subsequent calls.  Elasticsearch, in my experience, is really fast.  If it's taking that long then you're probably returning too much data.  This is also the reason why it's taking up so much storage space when you try to store it in the localDB.

Look at the data being returned to the consumer.  Try to filter the data to just what the consumer needs.  Implementing pagination could be helpful here.

Comment: The subset of data is already filtered based on user input and my application specification must be able to retrieve such quantity of data. I may need to add that my elastic search query are made to Kibana, it's not locally hosted. For example in debug I only ask for 100 logs (when I should ask for 6000~)  and it takes approximatively 1 minute. But I will look to implementing pagination.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a client-side framework such as Angular, React or Blazor Client.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/choose-between-traditional-web-and-single-page-apps